# Blender Python Data (equality works between instances, identity not)

Tags: python, scripting, mesh

In the first example, `a is b` returns True as it should. In the second, it is False. (assume Blender is just opened and the default cube is present and selected).  I thought I was starting to understand until I got `False`.  This is copied form the Python console.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a == b
True

>>> a is b
True

>>> a = bpy.context.active_object.data
>>> b = bpy.data.meshes[bpy.context.active_object.name]
>>> a
bpy.data.meshes['Cube']

>>> b
bpy.data.meshes['Cube']

>>> type(a)
<class 'bpy_types.Mesh'>

>>> type(b)
<class 'bpy_types.Mesh'>

>>> a == b
True

>>> a is b
False   # WHY?
```

Another example based on @ideasman42 explanation...

```
>>> a = bpy.context.object
>>> b = bpy.context.object
>>> a is b
False
```

Comment: Note, in this case `a=7; b=7'; a is b` is incidental, you cant **rely** on this behavior. Testing with `1000` here fails. - Edited question with an example that will work reliably.

Comment: The second example is incorrect, it assumes the object name matches the mesh name.

Comment: related pycon 2015 talk:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH4XF6pKKmk

Comment: It seems to got better over the years. In Blender 3.6 `bpy.context.object is bpy.context.object` and `bpy.context.active_object.data is bpy.data.meshes[bpy.context.active_object.name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you access `object.data` it will return a new instance,
however this is a very small data type to access the real mesh data stored in Blender.

Equality works as expected (and they have the same `__hash__`), so you can put them into `dict`/`set` types. You just can't rely on identity. (As with any 2 strings with the same content).

Comment: Each time bpy.data is accessed, the data is instanciated again? Really? So if I have 1000 mesh objects, and I operate on all of them in every frame...  YIKES!!!  Are they garbage collected efficiently?  How can I simply get a reference to the data, not another instance?

Comment: @uhoh, you can test it, but as it happens `bpy.data` no, elaborated answer since `object.data` will. Note that this also happens when you do operations such as `num + 1`, Python's GC is optimized for creating and throwing away many small objects. In this case a `Mesh` isn't taking significantly difference amount of memory to a number.

Comment: So @ideasman42 are you saying that it is a reference that it is instantiated, not the whole mesh, vertices, normals, etc? Is this explained clearly somewhere?

Comment: It could be explained *more* clearly, but see: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/info_quickstart.html#data-creation-removal

Answer (score 2):

In this case I am going to add an answer to my question - with my own choice of wording that makes it clear to me. It may help others in my situation.

The "I" in API stands for interface. Objects, data, etc. are really "in C" (so to speak) at all times. `bpy.context.objects`, `bpy.data.meshes` are not THE objects or meshes.

These are just "temporary conduits" that allow information to travel between your script and the "real" Blender program. They are instantiated each time they are used. This is why (for example):

```
>>> bpy.context.object is bpy.context.object
False
```

The wording in this [subsection](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/info_api_reference.html#nested-properties) of the API reference helped.